# Does a SQLITE database get reset on an app update?

Tags: sqlite, ios, app-store

I'm wondering whether to use CoreData or simple sqlite database for an iOS app. The app lets users add tons of data to the database and I want to make sure that if I use sqlite, the database won't get erased when the app is updated in the future. I know that CoreData doesn't get reset, does a sqlite file? If so, how can I prevent from it getting reset?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing gets reset when an app is updated.